# awk for column replacement

Tags: text-processing, awk, bioinformatics

I need to replace the column 1 of file 1, with column 1 of file 2, when column 1 of file 1 matches with col 5 of file 2.

file 1

```
ENSG00000237491    1     714150     745440      2       1  143562      
ENSG00000230092    1     736259     745541      2       1  143562    
ENSG00000269831    1     738532     739137      2       1  143562    
ENSG00000187634    1     860260     879955     26      20  130731
```

file 2

```
AL669831.1      1       738532  739137  ENSG00000269831
SAMD11          1       860260  879955  ENSG00000187634
RP11-206L10.9   1       714150  745440  ENSG00000237491
RP11-206L10.8   1       736259  745541  ENSG00000230092
```

Output should be like

```
RP11-206L10.9    1     714150     745440      2       1  143562      
RP11-206L10.8    1     736259     745541      2       1  143562    
AL669831.1       1     738532     739137      2       1  143562    
SAMD11           1     860260     879955     26      20  130731
```

I tried the codes below but it doesn't work, prints no output, stops immediately without any error.

```
 awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1;next} $5 in a {$1=a[$1];print}' FS='\t' OFS='\t' file1.txt file2.txt  > output.txt
```

Thank you!

Comment: From your example, it isn't exactly clear what you want. But you might get something out of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272717/inner-join-on-two-text-files

Comment: 1. your awk script should be reading file2 before file1.   2. the examples you've given won't produce any output with your awk script (or the algorithm you described) because there are no instances where any $5 of file2 matches any $1 of file1.  Provide input examples that can produce the output you want.   3. (untested) try `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$5]=$1; next}; $1 in a {$1=a[$1];print}' FS='\t' OFS='\t' file2.txt file1.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your `file1.txt` as above and an edited version of your `file2.txt` (so that there are some input lines in file2.txt where $5 is in file1.txt):

```
AL157931.1      13      23551994        23552136        ENSG00000237491
HMGA1P6 13      23708313        23708703        ENSG00000230092
RNY3P4  13      23726725        23726825        ENSG00000207157
```

Reading file2.txt before file1.txt, we can get the following output:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"}
       NR==FNR {a[$5]=$1; next};
       $1 in a {$1=a[$1];print}' file2.txt file1.txt 
AL157931.1      1       714150  745440  2       1       143562
HMGA1P6 1       736259  745541  2       1       143562
```

The key to how this works is in realising that we want to build an associative array where the keys are $5 from file2 and the values are $1 from the same file.

Then, when we loop over file1, check if $1 is a key in the array.  If so, replace  $1 with the matching value (i.e. the corresponding $1 from file2) and print the line.

Comment: Still, it doesn't do anything, no output, no error

Comment: are you sure your input files are tab delimited?   try getting rid of the BEGIN block.

Comment: It worked!! Thank you so so much!!!

Comment: is there a way i can keep the first line of file 1, which is the header line?

Comment: add `FNR==1 {print;next};` after the NR==FNR line.